# Can´t read CPU Temperature - Nodejs or WindowsForms

Tags: node.js, temperature, openhardwaremonitor

I´m trying to check my CPU Temperature (on an AMD FX-4100 on Windows 10) using a nodejs app (library https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation):

```
const si = require('systeminformation');
si.graphics()
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

And I just receive it back:

{ main: -1, cores: [], max: -1 }

The other informations (CPU Load, RAM Usage,...) is ok.

When I try to do the same reading on a WindowsForm Application (using OpenHardwareMonitor library):

```
    Computer c = new Computer()
            {
                GPUEnabled = true,
                CPUEnabled = true,
                MainboardEnabled = true,
                HDDEnabled = true,
                RAMEnabled = true,
                FanControllerEnabled = true
            };

(...)

    c.Open();

(...)

    foreach (var hardwadre in c.Hardware)
                {
                    if (hardwadre.HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU)
                    {
                        hardwadre.Update();
                        foreach (var sensor in hardwadre.Sensors)
                            Console.WriteLine("Sensores são: " + sensor.SensorType);
                    }
                }
```

Any temperature sensor also...

On UI mode of OpenHardwareMonitor or CPUID HwMonitor I can visualize it... What could be happening?

Thanks!!

Comment: My wild guess is that either `systeminformation` does not handle it properly or it is a permission issue. Are you running it as Admin or ordinary user? See here for a similar case: https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/systeminformation/issues/179